# cpu utilization reaches to 100% and jquery speek () function not working in linux

Tags: jquery, ajax, linux

When i open particular table in my application cpu usage reaches to 100%

my jquery get loaded still speek() not working. Wasted lot of time by trying to fix it.

also tried using setTimeout() still no luck.

```
function get_all_op_tkt()
{
     var timen = ' <?php echo date("d/m/Y  l h:i:s A");  ?>';
     // alert(timen);
    $('.page-header marquee').text('OP QUEUE :'+timen);
    $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>opqueue/get_op_all_lst",
            data:1,
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            // data: 'user_id='+id+'&<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>=<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',
            success: function(data){


                    $.each(data.spereakk, function (a, b) 
                    {
                        function speak(text) 
                        {
                        var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
                        var voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
                        msg.voice = voices[20];
                        msg.voiceURI = 'native';
                        msg.volume = 50;
                        msg.rate = 1/1.4;
                        msg.pitch = 25;
                        msg.text = text;
                        msg.lang = 'en-IN';
                        speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
                        }                                       
                        $('.spereakk').append('<tr class = "countin" text-align ="left"><td class = "countrno"><strong>'+b.token_no+'</strong></td><td class="countrnoo"><strong>'+b.consult_rm+'</strong></td></tr>');

                        speak('token number'+b.token_no+" "+'Room Number' +" "+b.consult_rm);
                        });
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("Network Error");
            }
        }); 

  clearInterval(get_all_op_tkt);
}



setInterval(function(){
get_all_op_tkt();
```

}, 1000);